# xquery- how to use a '.xq' file (containing functions) that is already being imported as a module in another '.xq' file (containing more functions)

Tags: xquery, flwor

I am using an Xquery file--> let us say file1.xq by importing it.

Now this file (file1.xq) imports another file file2.xq within it.

I not only want to use the functions of file1.xq, but I also want to use the functions of file2.xq.

So I tried importing both into my actual xquery code (that uses functions from both the files) but I got a duplicate function definition error.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I use the Xquery functions defined in file2.xq in my Xquery code? Esp. when in this case, the functions of file2.xq are being utilised by file1.xq (which is also imported by my xquery code)?

Answer (score 3):

You probably did not define a proper namespace. Therefore, the default namespace was used and if you have two functions within different files they will map to the same function and a duplicate function definition error should occur. 
It's difficult to guess as you did not provide any sample code or more detailed code.

So lets say your file2.xq should declare its namespace using

```
module namespace _ = 'http://mycompany.org/file1';
```

You can then define the your functions within this file using

```
declare function :my-function() { "Whatever" }
```

This module can now be imported within your actual xquery code file using

```
import module namespace file1 = 'http://mycompany.org/file1';
file1:my-function()
```

You can also use

```
import module namespace file1 = 'http://mycompany.org/file1' at '/path/in/local/filesystem';
```

To specify the location of file1.xq absolutely.

Comment: here with ref to your example, i wish to use file1.xq within another file file2.xq, as well as within mainfile.xq(which is the file I will actually run)--at the same time file2.xq is also required by mainfile.xq, i.e. file2->file1 and mainfile->file1 and mainfile->file2...how do i import resp. files for these 3 imports? thanks...